# Show notification in last place in notification tray

Tags: android, android-notifications

So, I want to show my notification as the last one in the notification tray. The Last.fm app does it. It shows the notification, the date shown is the date that the notification was created, but in the notification tray, it shows in as the last notification, even after older notifications.

I tried to do this with Priorities, but it didn't work.

So, how do I do it? It's possibile because another app does it, but does anyone knows how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vdlow-post ur code..!

Answer (score 0):

I finally done it using priorities. I was just using it the wrong way before.